# Setting .Net CLR Version in IIS to "No Managed Code" using Powershell within ADO Pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

Azure Powershell 7.0

My company is now rolling out some apps using. NetCore using an Classic ADO Pipeline. As part of the pipeline we need to test if the site exists. If not, then we need to configure it in IIS before deploying code. We are doing this using Powershell. The script is run from a file and not inline. To configure the App Pool .Net CLR version I have:

Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPoolName" -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value $managedRuntime

$managedRuntime is defined in a global library in Azure as "". From what I've been reading setting managedRuntimeVersion to "" is how you would set it to "No Managed Code". However, when I run the script it sets the CLR version in the App Pool (in IIS) to "[managedruntimeversion]". This is all only running on DevOps servers, and I would like to have this all worked out before taking it to our Development or Production environments.

If someone could help me sort this all out is would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @StevenB, may i know if there's any update? You can use `No Managed Code` or `$null` as string parameter to the script, please refer to the reply for the details, let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

To set the agent pool .Net CLR Version in IIS to "No Managed Code", you can use script:

setCLR.ps1 content:

```
param (
    [string]$appPoolName,
    [string]$managedRuntime
)
Import-Module WebAdministration
Set-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\$appPoolName" -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value $managedRuntime
```

And invoke it:

```
.\setCLR.ps1 -appPoolName "testpool1" -managedRuntime "No Managed Code"
```

Or

```
.\setCLR.ps1 -appPoolName "testpool1" -managedRuntime $null"
```

[image]